# Is it possible to create organization (under sub-org) at depth more than one level in wso2 b2b ciam solution?

Tags: wso2, b2b, wso2-asgardeo

Is it possible to create organization (under sub-org) at depth more than one level in wso2 b2b ciam solution? I see in asgardeo cloud demo setup, i can only create sub-orgs under org and thats it. I can not create a sub-org under sub-org.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create sub-org under sub-org. You need to have a paid subscription to use this feature.
Please refer: https://wso2.com/asgardeo/docs/guides/organization-management/manage-b2b-organizations/manage-suborganizations/#create-a-sub-organization-for-your-sub-organization